# How to achieve this using linq?

Tags: c#, linq

```
int cell = 1;
foreach (var item in resourceDictionary.Keys)
{
    excelSheet.Cells[cell, 1] = item;
    excelSheet.Cells[cell, 2] = resourceDictionary[item];
        cell++;
}
```

Is there any easiest way to achieve this using linq in c#?

Comment: linq would mask the behavior. its not recommended.

Comment: Why do you want to use LINQ?

Comment: LINQ is for querying. Don't abuse LINQ for updates. If it would be for updating, it would have been named LINU...

Comment: why do you need to fix it if it's not broken? did you just find out about Linq? if so - you're the victim of "recency bias" (look it up)

Comment: @ASHOKA: LINQ is not magic. It uses loops internally too. So why should it be faster? If anything, it adds a little overhead compared to a plain loop.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You code doesn't need LINQ. If `resourceDictionary` implements `IDictionary<TKey, TValue>`, then the following is probablly the more readable / efficient you could have:

```
int cell = 1;
foreach (var item in resourceDictionary)
{
    excelSheet.Cells[cell, 1] = item.Key;
    excelSheet.Cells[cell, 2] = item.Value;
    cell++;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

If you want it:

```
resourceDictionary.Select((p, i) => new {p.Key, p.Value, Cell = i + 1})
   .ToList()
   .ForEach(item => {
         excelSheet.Cells[item.Cell, 1] = item.Key;
         excelSheet.Cells[item.Cell, 2] = item.Value;
           });
```

Comment: The OP wants to use LINQ to improve performance. Copying the dictionary to a new list would surely result in the contrary. The performance of the shown code is worse than that of the original one.

Comment: I did not notice OP's comment about performance. But anyway.

Comment: Also note that `List.ForEach` is not a part of LINQ at all, only the `Select` is.